# Metrics for image/visual complexity in computer vision/graphics?

Tags: graphs, reference-request, image-processing

Could anyone kindly point me to revenant literature in computer vision/graphics that detail on metrics for image/visual complexity and how to regularize that?

More specifically, I am trying to design a neural algorithm for creating business logos and one major difference from image generation problems in CV/CG is the simplicity required of logos. I have been thinking along the lines of adding a visual/image complexity term to be regularized and penalized as the algorithm learns the balance between lower-level style and higher-level meaning/content of multidimensional input images and descriptions. I have been searching along but couldn't find related resources... Could anyone shed some light on that?

Comment: Crossposted: http://ai.stackexchange.com/q/2293/1794, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/65560/755.
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.